# Is it must to use 3rd party framework to use to develop adobe stage3d game

Tags: stage3d

I was searching for tutorials to develop games using stage3d. Every where I came across the articles/tutorials using the frameworks.

Is it compulsory to use the frameworks? or its very difficult to do it without frame works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look how to do Stage3D without framework

http://www.packtpub.com/adobe-flash11-stage3d-molehill-game-programming-beginners-guide/book#overview

It is definitely easier to use framework, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

The fact you're asking the question and your Nickname makes it simple to answer that yes, you don't want to mess with low level molehill. Try Away3D, learn some general 3D concepts and only then think if it's worth to optimize your game by working with stage3D directly.